# AbstractSpliterator implementation with unknown size throws OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have got a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` when I use an `AbstractSpliterator` implementation, which reports an unknown size.

In this case I defined a class `StreamCollapse` which extends `AbstractSpliterator` and merges series of adjacent elements in `tryAdvance()` implementation. Its constructor calls the super constructor as `super(Long.MAX_VALUE, source.characteristics())`.

Regarding the [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator.html#AbstractSpliterator-long-int-) I was expecting that using a `Long.MAX_VALUE` indicates an unknown size. However, it seems it is trying to allocate memory with that size, instead.

Why is it trying to allocate that space? What value should I use for estimated size?

Here it is an example test:

```
Stream<Integer> nrs = Stream.of(3, 3, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4 ,5 , 5);
Integer [] expected = {3, 5, 3, 4, 5};
Object[] actual = collapse(nrs).toArray();
assertEquals(actual, expected);
```

And the `collapse()` method implementation:

```
static <T> Stream<T> collapse(Stream<T> source) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(
            new StreamCollapse<T>(source.spliterator()), false);
}

class StreamCollapse<T> extends AbstractSpliterator<T> implements Consumer<T> {

    private final Spliterator<T> source;
    private T curr = null;

    StreamCollapse(Spliterator<T> source) {
        super(Long.MAX_VALUE, source.characteristics());
        this.source = source;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
        T prev = curr;
        boolean hasNext;
        while ((hasNext = source.tryAdvance(this)) && curr.equals(prev)) { }
        if(hasNext) action.accept(curr);
        return hasNext;
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(T item) {
        curr = item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should remove the characteristics from your composited spliterator, for example:

```
// an unknown spliterator shouldn't having SIZED | SUBSIZED  characteristics
//                                             v  
super(Long.MAX_VALUE, source.characteristics() & (~(SIZED | SUBSIZED)));
```

**WHEN** a Spliteartor is a [SIZED](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#SIZED) Spliteartor, [Spliterator#getExactSizeIfKnown](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#getExactSizeIfKnown--) will be used by stream to create an array.

> Characteristic value signifying that the value returned from `estimateSize()` prior to **traversal** or **splitting** represents a **finite** size that, in the absence of structural source modification, represents an exact count of the number of elements that would be encountered by a complete traversal.

**IF** the stream run in parallel the [Stream#toArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray--) will throws a `IllegalArgumentException` if the *estimateSize* >= `Long.MAX_VALUE - 8`.

**IF** the stream is a sequentially stream the [Stream#toArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray--) will grows its internal array capacity to the *estimateSize*.

Comment: That’s the correct answer, the spliterator *must* clear the `SIZED` and `SUBSIZED` characteristics. As an addition, using the `estimateSize()` of the source spliterator as estimated size of the filtering spliterator would be a good approach. After all, the actual size will be somewhere between zero and that source size. That’s how `filter` does it too and the current implementation will deal with that much better than with entirely unknown sizes.

Comment: @Holger thank you for audit my answer. I also get your suggestion too.